# Rewriting sass url when building project

Tags: javascript, css, url-rewriting, sass, webpack

I'm using webpack-dev-server during development and have a public folder as content base containing: index.html, img/**.*.jpg.

During development in my sass file i reference images as:

```
background-image: url('img/background.jpg');
```

This works fine during development since webpack-dev-server is serving the images in the public folder.

But when I build the project and generate a dist folder that is later going to be deployed to a test server I need to rewrite all the urls in the sass files since they aren't going to be served from the root of the webserver. In my case I would like to rewrite the previous css rule as:

```
background-image: url('folder1/folder2/folder3/img/background.jpg');
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with environment variables using sass-loader.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  sassLoader: {
    data: "$env: " + process.env.NODE_ENV + ";"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.  I would recommend you instead keep your paths relative to the folder you're currently in.  For instance, have an `assets` folder that has both `img`, `sass`, etc.  Then, your paths could be relative to the `assets` root as opposed to needing to traverse to a separate build folder.  That way it won't matter if you're in `build`, `dist` or otherwise.

For example:

```
|assets
|-sass
|--my_styles.scss
|--SUBSTYLES
|---my_substyles.scss
|-img
|--my_img.png
```

and your paths would then be:

```
url(../img/my_img.png) //For my_styles.scss
```

and

```
url(../../img/my_img.png) //For my_substyles.scss
```

---

Otherwise, you'll need to keep a separate variable file per server/build type that defines a `ROOT_PATH` variable and appends it in your SASS.  Something along the lines of

```
url($ROOT_PATH + 'img/my_img.png')
```

which could always be wrapped in a mixin to be used more easily.

Comment: That structure you suggested isn't an option for me since I'm using Angular2 where every sass file is at the same level as the corresponding component it belongs to. Then I'm also using webpack to compile everything into a single bundle.js.

Comment: Second option should work, it's just a PITA.  However, I'm unfamiliar with Angular2's restrictions. Hopefully you'll get a response which works for you.